# Legendre Polynomials as solutions for Laplace’s equation with azimuthal symmetry

Tags: electrostatics, angular-momentum, spherical-harmonics

(very amateur) physics student/enthusiast here. While reading Griffith’s textbook on electrodynamics I came across this line about separation of variables solutions for Laplace’s equations, assuming azimuthal symmetry. The $\ell(\ell+1)$ is the separation constant between the functions of $\theta$ and $r$ that come about when you perform separation of variables.

No matter how I do it, I cannot get this differential equation in the right form for it to be a Legendre differential equation, even with the hint provided that the variable is $x=\cos(\theta)$. Figured if anyone knew how to do it, it’d be someone here.

[image]

Comment: Could you please use MathJax to type the equations and avoid posting images instead of typing the questions yourself. You can use the “quote” feature if you’d like to make clear which part is from a textbook or other source.

Comment: Also, can you please show the steps you do. Right now you are essentially asking for the whole derivation. Does something like [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplacesEquationSphericalCoordinates.html) help?